# GUI extensions for Experience Space - Open ContentExplorerPanel

Tags: gui-extensions, tridion-sites, experience-space, sites-10

I am trying to open a custom modal pop up from experince space to show list of item (component and pages). I do see list of built-in panel of the Content Explore in the node modules with below list of ID but I was not able to figure out how i can use it to show list of item using these built in panel.

```
/**
 * List of all built-in panel IDs of the Content Explorer.
 *
 * @public
 */
export declare const contentExplorerPanelIds: readonly ["information", "general", "metadata", "history", "blueprint", "where-used", "view-on-site", "published-to", "translations"];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tridion Sites 10.0 includes extension points for:

- Primary navigation (e.g., add a new view alongside Content and
  Activities)
- Actions (add a new button or context menu option to the Content and
  Activities views)
- Tables (add custom columns to the Content and Activities tables)
- Fields (e.g., render a text field as a color picker)
- Rich text editor (customize its functionality and behavior)

On release, 10.0 didn't include an extension point for managing the panels in the Insights area.

However, in the next week or so we will be releasing a UX update for Tridion Sites 10.0 (delivered as a mandatory hotfix) that adds this functionality as well as a number of other significant enhancements (e.g., publishing queue) to the Experience Space UI. We will also include a new extension example in our public GitHub repository showing how to add, remove, and re-order panels using this new extension point.

Comment: could we add the github repo here?

Comment: The public examples for the Tridion Sites 10 UX update are now available. Here are a couple concerning the new Insights area extension point: [In bundles panel](https://github.com/RWS/tridion-sites-extensions-examples/tree/main/sites-10-ux-update/content-explorer/in-bundle-insights-panel-addon), [History compare panel](https://github.com/RWS/tridion-sites-extensions-examples/tree/main/sites-10-ux-update/content-explorer/history-diff-insights-panel-addon)